# How to replace missing values in ID variable

Tags: r

My data frame consists of observations (rows) from two different survey waves (as indicated by the column "wave"). There are two id columns ("student_id" and "student_id_room"). Each of the two id columns can uniquely identify each student on its own. However, in survey wave 1, some students reported only their "student_id" while other students reported only their "student_id_room". In survey wave 2, all students reported both the "student_id" and "student_id_room". How can I replace the NAs in "student_id" and "student_id_room" with the correct values?

This is the data frame:

```
student_id <- c(1718,NA,1901)
student_id_room <- c(NA,12,NA)
var1 <- c(17,18,41)
wave_1 <- data.frame(student_id,
                     student_id_room,
                     var1)

rm(student_id,
   student_id_room,
   var1)

student_id <- c(1718,1801,1901)
student_id_room <- c(24,12,6)
var1 <- c(31,32,43)
wave_2 <- data.frame(student_id,
                     student_id_room,
                     var1)

rm(student_id,
   student_id_room,
   var1)

all_waves <- lst(wave_1,
                 wave_2) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="wave")
```

This is how I want the data frame to look like:

```
wave <- c("wave_1","wave_1","wave_1","wave_2","wave_2","wave_2")
student_id <- c(1718,1801,1901,1718,1801,1901)
student_id_room <- c(24,12,6,24,12,6)
var1 <- c(17,18,41,31,32,43)
all_waves_revised <- data.frame(wave,
                                student_id,
                                student_id_room,
                                var1)
```

Comment: Are all the students represented in the same rows, in the same order?

Comment: Please share the output of `packageVersion("dplyr")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a new ID column, (`index`), then mutate or summarise to get the collapsed values grouped by the new index (with `keep` or `coalesce`), and finally drop the index.

```
# with keep

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

all_waves |> 
    mutate(index = row_number(), .by = wave) |>
    mutate(across(starts_with('student_id'),
                  \(x) keep(x, !is.na(x))),
           .by = index)

# with coalesce

library(dplyr)

all_waves |> 
    mutate(index = row_number(), .by = wave) |>
    mutate(across(starts_with('student_id'),
                  \(x) coalesce(x[1], x[2])),
           .by = index)

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  index wave   student_id student_id_room  var1
  <int> <chr>       <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 wave_1       1718              24    17
2     2 wave_1       1801              12    18
3     3 wave_1       1901               6    41
4     1 wave_2       1718              24    31
5     2 wave_2       1801              12    32
6     3 wave_2       1901               6    43
```

**edit with method for old dplyr versions**

If we have an old version of `dplyr` (<1.1.0), we have to use `group_by |> transformationz |> ungroup`, instead of `.by`:

```
all_waves |> 
    group_by(wave) |> 
    mutate(index = row_number()) |>
    group_by(index) |> 
    mutate(across(starts_with('student_id'),
                  \(x) coalesce(x[1], x[2]))) |> 
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Both solutions don't work. See Update #1 in the appended original post.

Comment: See if the updated answer helps

Comment: The coalesce answer does work, as shown in the answer. I suspect, from the output shown in the #update, that you did not use it correctly or may be using and old dplyr version. Because the results do not seem to be grouped by the row id, and because you have a `.by` column. I suspect you either do not have the latest dplyr version (`.by`is recent, version 1.1.0) or included .by in the wrong place

Comment: You are absolutely right. My bad. After I updated dplyr, both of your solutions work. Thanks a lot for your help.